# iterate multiple list and pass element of each list item to a method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs to iterate the list. I have two list object which i want to iterate and get the values and pass it to a method.

I want the first element of list1 and first element of list2.second element of list1 and second element of list2..

Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/tg7A6VVySu6hlb6hR06F?p=preview

In the below code, i have $scope.list and $scope.itemsPurchased.

When i print the values `console.log(firstName + " -- " + item);` i was expecting as below:

```
 Joe -- laptop
Mishal -- fridge
Dex -- AC
Rayan -- Mobile
Riyya -- Heater
```

js code:

```
app.controller("BaseController", function($scope) { 
  $scope.title = "Angular.ForEach";
  $scope.list = [
    {firstname: 'Joe', lastname: 'Michael'},
    {firstname: 'Mishal', lastname: 'A'},
    {firstname: 'Dex', lastname: 'T'},
    {firstname: 'Rayan', lastname: 'K'},
    {firstname: 'Riyya', lastname: 'R'}
  ];

  $scope.itemsPurchased = [
    {item: 'laptop'},
    {item: 'fridge'},
    {item: 'AC'},
    {item: 'Mobile'},
    {item: 'Heater'}
  ]; 
        var i;
         angular.forEach($scope.list, function (value, key) {
           i=1;
        var firstName = JSON.stringify(value.firstname);
        angular.forEach($scope.itemsPurchased, function (value) {
            var item = JSON.stringify(value.item, value.value);
             console.log(firstName + "  item : " + item);
             //method call
             //showData(firstName,item);
        });
    }); 
});
```

Any suggestions, as with my code each name is mapped to every element in the item..**In my list i dont have any id to compare**.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't use a simple for?

```
for (let i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
    doSomethingWith(list1[i], list2[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both lists are parallel arrays, you only need to loop through one. The index will be the same. Where you got confused is that you tried to loop through both of them.

```
var i = 0;
angular.forEach($scope.list, function (value, key) {

 console.log(value.firstname + "  item : " + $scope.itemsPurchased[i].item);
 i++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.list, function (item, index) {
   var firstName = item.firstname;
   console.log(firstName + " -- " + $scope.itemsPurchased[index].item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in order to help you, I would need more context about what are you trying to achieve. And in the other hand the way you are saving (local or db) the customer data and purchased items is kinda inconsistent. And why are you using JSON.stringify to get a list value?

But according to your code and assuming that both lists will always have the same length (what is as I said pretty magic programming :D ) you need to loop both lists with a for and do something like this :

```
for(let i=0; i<list.lenth; i++){ 
    const customerName = $scope.list[i];
    const item = $scope.itemsPurchased[i];
    showData({customerName, item});

}
const showData = ({customerName, item}) => {
    console.log(`${customerName} -- ${item}`);
}
```

But as I said try to refactor your code a little bit.